# Scala union operation on binary search tree

Tags: scala, binary-search-tree

I'm new to Scala and I got stuck with undestanding how does following code [from this link](https://github.com/frankh/coursera-scala/blob/master/objsets/src/main/scala/objsets/TweetSet.scala) works on binary search tree:

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    (left union (right union that)).incl(elem)
}

def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
    if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else this
}
```

Thing that I don't get is how does union operation creating new Tree in sorted order and how it exactly works, is it going to the end of tree and then adding elements one-by-one ?
Also I don't get how does this recursion would terminate, in terms of Java it should probably give us NullPointerException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sum up how the algorithm works (since only part of it is in the question, the termination being in the `Empty` case):

To make the union of two `TweetSet`s, look at the left one:

- if it is empty, the union should be the other one, so `Empty union that == that`
- if it is non-empty, then it has a root element `elem`, a `left` sub-tree and a `right` sub-tree. The union is then formed by all the elements in `left`, in `right`, in `that`, and the element `elem`, so we call recursively `union` on all of those.

In this last case, to ensure that we get to termination, the left element in each `union` call should be smaller than the initial call (otherwise, we will get caught in a recursion loop where the left-hand-side of `union` will be bigger and bigger). The expression

```
left union (right union that)
```

does precisely that:

- `right` is smaller than the initial `NonEmpty(elem, left, right)` (being its right sub-tree), so `right union that` will eventually get computed
- `left` is also smaller than the initial tree, so `left union (...)` will also get computed eventually.

Then we add the final missing element `elem` to build the final `TweetSet`. Note that if you try and apply this algorithm for small sets, it comes back to adding all the elements of the first set to the second, one by one, starting with the greatest one (the furthest one on the right in the initial tree). In particular, the size of the second set does not influence the length of the algorithm.